# How do I make my rain effect look more like rain and less like snowfall?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am making a game in that game I want a rain effect. I am little bit far from this right now. I am creating the rain effect like below:

```
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ColorInitializer(1, 1, 1));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new AlphaInitializer(0));
particleSystem.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityInitializer(2, 2, 20, 10));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new RotationInitializer(0.0f, 30.0f));

particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ScaleModifier(1.0f, 2.0f, 0, 150));
particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1, 1, 1, 1f, 1, 1, 1, 3));
particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1, 1, 1f, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6));
particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaModifier(0, 1, 0, 3));
particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 1, 125));
particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ExpireModifier(50, 50));

scene.attachChild(particleSystem);
```

But it looks like snowfall! What changes can I do for it to look more like rain?

**EDIT** Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't parse these lines of codes into an image inside my head ;). If you can show us an image or video I'm sure we can give you some tips.

Comment: its only a blank screen and its show particle like snow i just want particle show like rain effect @RoyT.

Comment: @NikhilLamba We still would appreciate a screenshot.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs : how we can add screnshot in Question , i am new in this that's y

Comment: @NikhilLamba Upload it to [imgur](http://www.imgur.com/) then link to it. See the [formatting help](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for how to create links. You can't add images into your posts yet since you haven't unlocked that privilege - so for now just go with a link.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs : i upload my snapshot http://i.imgur.com/bRIMP.png

Comment: @RoyT.:i upload my snapshot of rain effect http://i.imgur.com/bRIMP.png

Comment: You should try making the rain sprites more blue and more long stretched. Use this (http://ridingwiththeriver.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/rain-fall-animation.gif ) as a reference image.

Comment: +1 Nikhil, a nice improvement on your last question.

Comment: @RoyT.: Thanx for reference image :)

Comment: @Byte56 : you teach me a lesson from that lesson i learn a  lot , thanx for that :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fundamentally, it looks like snow because the particles are round and they don't convey motion in any way. Rain drops are typically seen as elongated droplets, even to the point at which they are lines rather than particles. Think of a scene where you are looking out of a window at a rainstorm: you're not seeing individual drops suspended in the air, you're seeing the streak of the path they follow.

You could try stretching the particles out along one axis, but I think you're not going to be able to get a rain-like effect with particles like these.

Comment: Here's an example of such a rain effect in a 2D game: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPurN4ZBiow&feature=player_detailpage#t=8s Though I must admit it looked better in my memory. :-)

Comment: Here's an example of rain: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9GOB6DSMZs

Comment: @MrCranky : Thanx a lot for ur answer , as u said "but I think you're not going to be able to get a rain-like effect with particles like these" then how can we do ?

Comment: @Eric : Thanx for youtube Link :)

Comment: @Pubby : thanx for Link :)

Comment: I wrote up a more comprehensive answer here which is probably applicable. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29235/where-to-start-creating-a-2d-rain-simulation-with-opengl-es-1-1/30137#30137

Comment: @MrCranky : Thanx 4 this link , and ur answer :)

Comment: +1 I made a rain only from about 20-40% opacity lines randomly drawn, and the effect was very realistic, maybe even too realistic, because it wasn't very visible. Look at the rain, it's hard to actually see it, that's why you rather look through window on ground on puddles, not on air, to see if it's raining.

Answer (score 4):

Also, aside from what MrCranky said, rain does not really have a color, it more just deforms the world around it, so to get accurate rain you really need to be using shaders. That said, you can fake it using long streaks (like what MrCranky said) that are all in line with eachother

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer , But as u said "that are all in line with eachother" as i am using a Sprite as a rain partilce how can i use line attach with each other

Comment: well i mean just use the same angle for the streaks (it should be like a line)

Answer (score 3):

Snow "Flutters like a Feather" and Rain "Falls with a Flop"

Simple solution may simply be to increase the gravity so rain drops falls faster and less "snow like"

Making snow versus rain has the following characteristics

- Snow is basically a solid round thing that doesn't deform
- Snow has air resistance / drag so it falls slowly and gracefully with a relatively low maximum velocity
- Snow is easily affected by air turbulence (example, a wind affector) and zigs and zags as it descends ... and event ascends for that realistic feel of a passing breeze

Rain is pretty much the opposite of the above Snow

- Rain deforms as it falls

  - easiest visual change is to stretch the rain drop sprite based on the speed of the raindrop
  - this gives the impression of motion and speed
- Rain is less affected by wind or air resistence

  - a strong wind affector can nudge the path of descent but only mildly (and really only worth accounting for this if more realism is the goal)

So ...

- As the others suggest, use a sprite sheet to animate the drops as they fall

  - sprite sheet of event two sub-sprites is useful ... example: "drop" and "splash"
- Stretch the texture to give motion

  - scaled relative to a min/max velocity range (eg, normalize 0..1 and scale "drop" accordingly when you paint the texture)
- stronger gravity

  - potentially "substantially" more than your environment's normal gravity to make rain have a good "look and feel"

Answer (score 1):

You're only going to be able to get so far with just changing the graphics. I'd personally start with long blue rectangles and stylize it from there. Look at how Minecraft does raindrops.

What's really going to make it feel like rain is the sound you use. Find a free rain ambient track somewhere on the internet and loop it. As long as there are enough particles and they're moving fast enough downwards your mind will make the connection to rain.